# ¿Cómo hago para que funcione mi ciclo do while?

Tags: c, dev-c++

Tengo escrito este programa en C y aparentemente está bien ya que no marca ningún error y si compila y corre bien, pero no repite el ciclo do while. El programa me de el total de la compra con los descuentos aplicados, pero no repite el proceso si es que le digo que si quiero hacer otra compra, tampoco regresa un monto final, solo deja de trabajar después de la pregunta de si/no

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float precioRopa, precioComes, precioPerf, total, totalFin;
    float descRopa, descComes, descPerf;
    char resp;
    
    printf("Programa que te ayuda a calcular lo recaudado al final del d%ca seg%cn las compras y los descuentos aplicados\n",161,163);
    do {
        printf("Inserta el monto total de la compra del departamento de ropa:\n");
        scanf("%f",&precioRopa);
        printf("Inserta el monto total de la compra del departamento de comestibles:\n");
        scanf("%f",&precioComes);
        printf("Inserta el monto total de la compra del departamento de perfumería:\n");
        scanf("%f",&precioPerf);
        if (precioRopa>100) {
            descRopa = precioRopa*.95;
        } else {
            descRopa = precioRopa;
        }
        if (precioComes>100) {
            descComes = precioComes*.965;
        } else {
            descComes = precioComes;
        }
        if (precioPerf>100) {
            descPerf = precioPerf*.92;
        } else {
            descPerf = precioPerf;
        }
        total = descRopa+descComes+descComes;
        totalFin = totalFin+total;
        printf("Su total es de: $%f\n",total);
        printf("Desea hacer una nueva compra? (si/no) \n");
        scanf("%s",resp);
    } while (strcmp(resp,"no")!=0);
    printf("Lo recaudado al final del d%ca es de: $%f\n",163,totalFin);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analizando tu programa, veo que utilizas `strcmp` que sirve para comparar cadenas de caracteres, lo cual es correcto, pero debes incluir la cabecera `<string.h>`. Te debe salir un *warning* en la consola al ejecutar el programa.

Dices que tu programa no ejecuta bien el `do while`, es porque estas haciendo esto `while (strcmp(resp,"no")!=0)`, guardar en la variable `resp` el `string` *"si"* o *"no"* según lo que desees hacer, pero tienes dicha variable declarada como `char`, con lo que en la línea:

```
 printf("Desea hacer una nueva compra? (si/no) \n");
 scanf("%s",resp);
```

En la variable `resp` solo guardarías 's' o 'n'

Para solucionar esto debes declarar dicha variable así: `char resp[2];`. Así podrás guardar *"si"* o *"no"*

Tu ejemplo completo quedaría así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    float precioRopa, precioComes, precioPerf, total, totalFin;
    float descRopa, descComes, descPerf;
    char resp[2];

    printf("Programa que te ayuda a calcular lo recaudado al final del d%ca seg%cn las compras y los descuentos aplicados\n",161,163);

    do {
        printf("Inserta el monto total de la compra del departamento de ropa:\n");
        scanf("%f",&precioRopa);
        printf("Inserta el monto total de la compra del departamento de comestibles:\n");
        scanf("%f",&precioComes);
        printf("Inserta el monto total de la compra del departamento de perfumería:\n");
        scanf("%f",&precioPerf);
    
        if (precioRopa>100) {
            descRopa = precioRopa*0.95;
        } else {
            descRopa = precioRopa;
        }
        if (precioComes>100) {
            descComes = precioComes*0.965;
        } else {
            descComes = precioComes;
        }
        if (precioPerf>100) {
            descPerf = precioPerf*0.92;
        } else {
            descPerf = precioPerf;
        }
    
        total = descRopa+descComes+descComes;
        totalFin = totalFin+total;
    
        printf("Su total es de: $%f\n",total);
        printf("Desea hacer una nueva compra? (si/no) \n");
        scanf("%s",resp);
    
    } while (strcmp(resp,"no")!=0);

    printf("Lo recaudado al final del d%ca es de: $%f\n",163,totalFin);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya funciona correctamente